# call a function from DialogFragment to Fragment without using LiveData

Tags: android, kotlin, android-dialogfragment

I'm trying to communicate between a `LoginFragment` and a reset password dialog fragment `DialogFragment`.

In the `DialogFragment` when a certain task is successful the dialog closes and I want to tell the `LoginFragment` to make a snackbar.

The way I'm doing it right now is using a Shared `ViewModel` between `LoginFragment` and `DialogFragment` and a `MutableLiveData`.

**SharedViewModel:**

```
class LoginViewModel(private val state: SavedStateHandle) : ViewModel() {
    // used to notify the user when dialog fragment closes with onSuccessListener
    // that the email has been sent using a snackbar
    val snackbarMessageLiveData = MutableLiveData<String>()

    val loginDetailsBundleLiveData = state.getLiveData<Bundle>("login_bundle")
}
```

**DialogFragment:**

```
task?.let {
    // email sent successfully
    it.addOnSuccessListener {
        // update user that an email has been sent
        viewModel.snackbarMessageLiveData.postValue(getString(R.string.password_recovery_email_sent))
        // closes the fragment
        dialog?.dismiss()
}
```

**LoginFragment:**

```
viewModel.snackbarMessageLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
    makeSnackbar(it)
})
```

This is the line that I use to update the livedata:
`viewModel.snackbarMessageLiveData.postValue(getString(R.string.password_recovery_email_sent))`

**However, this brings up some bugs:**

Every time I navigate to another fragment and then navigate back to `LoginFragment` the `loginDetailsBundleLiveData`  observer calls `makeSnackbar`.

I found an ugly workaround... but I was hoping there's a solution not using livedata's

*Note: I use the navigation component to call the dialog

```
val action = fragmentDirections.actionLoginFragmentToDialogPasswordRecoveryFragment()
binding.btnForgotPassword.setOnClickListener {
    findNavController().navigate(action)
}
```

I would like to know if there is a better way to do it? Maybe using an interface?

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: Updated.... Create interface inside of dialog, then implement it in activity or create it as variable, then create a public method "showSnackbar" and call it when interface was fired

Answer (score 0):

Use this extension functions and I hope it will help you

```
fun Fragment.setNavigationResult(result: Any?, key: String = 
"result") =findNavController().previousBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.set(key, result)


fun <T> Fragment.getNavigationResult(key: String = "result") =findNavController().currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.getLiveData<T?>(key)
```